# Share scheme in iOS Xcode project using command line

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcode5

[It is known how to enable shared for Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeManage.html)

Is it possible to do the same with Command line using xcodebuild or any?